# Space-filling curve of index greater than $\frac 12$

Tags: calculus, geometry

Is there any space-filling curve of index greater than $\frac 12$. I mean an **onto** function $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow [0,1]\times [0,1]$ such that for all $x,y$, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^\alpha$.Where $\alpha > \frac 12$ (the index) and $C$ are constants.

Comment: I presume you mean $f(x)−f(y)$ not $f(x)−f(x)$?

Comment: @dorchard sure. Thanks. I have corrected.

Comment: I didn't notice that your question is tagged with "calculus" rather than "real-analysis". Then I wonder if the approach in my answer with the concept of Lebesgue measure is appropriate?

Comment: Hi, A A. Is there any feedback?

Comment: @Landscape I you have guessed correctly I did not understand your approach.

Comment: Then will you accept the following statement? Let $B_1,\dots,B_n$ be some disks in the plane, and the sum of their areas is less than $1$, then $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ cannot be contained in $\cup_{i=1}^n B_i$. If you can accept this statement, I can provide an answer only using it.

Comment: @Landscape sounds natural.

Comment: I added all the details I could provide in my answer. Hope you will be satisfied with that.

Comment: @Landscape That was useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The image of an interval of length $2r$ under $f$ is contained in a disk of radius $Cr^\alpha$. Using this fact you may show that the two dimensional Lebesgue measure of $f([0,1])$ is $0$.

---

**Details added:** Given $n\ge 1$, divide $[0,1]$ into subintervals $I_{n,k}=[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]$, $k=0,\dots,n-1$. Denote $x_{n,k}=\frac{2k+1}{2n}$, $r_n=\frac{C}{(2n)^\alpha}$, and denote $B_{n,k}$ the disk centered at $f(x_{n,k})$ of radius $r_n$. Note that $x_{n,k}$ is the midpoint of $I_{n,k}$, so when $x\in I_{n,k}$, 
$$|x-x_{n,k}|\le\frac{1}{2n}\Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(x_{n,k})|\le \frac{C}{(2n)^\alpha}=r_n\Longrightarrow f(x)\in B_{n,k}.$$
Therefore, 
$$f(I_{n,k})\subset B_{n,k},\  0\le k\le n-1\Longrightarrow f([0,1])\subset\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1}B_{n,k}. $$
However,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\rm area}(B_{n,k})=n\times \pi r_n^2=\frac{\pi C}{2^\alpha}n^{1-2\alpha}.$$
Since $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$, as $n\to\infty$, the sum of the areas of $B_{n,k}$,  $k=0,\dots,n-1$ tends to $0$. It implies the Lebesgue measure of $f([0,1])$ is zero. In particular, when $n$ is large, $\cup_{k=0}^{n-1}B_{n,k}$ cannot cover $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: If you are familiar with Hausdorff dimension, a similar argument implies that the Hausdorff dimension of $f([0,1])$ is no more than $1/\alpha$, which is strictly less than $2$.